# How to take the screenshot of my application using a service?

Tags: android, screenshot

I would like to know if it possible to take a screen shot while i am playing a video using my application. If it possible, how can i implement it?

Will service be of any use here?

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/